# Data Model enquiry

Tags: oracle, data-modeling

Folks,

I have a around 2 million assets that send 15 min interval data for a given day (i.e) total of 96 intervals for a given day. What is best database modeling approach. My target RDBMS is Oracle.

I'm partitioning by week and for each interval I need to store the interval type (INT_TYPE) (i.e) actual or estimated etc.,

Option--1 will be way too deep in terms of data.

Option--2 can minimize the volume, but how do i model the column interval-type in Option--2? such that we can capture the interval type??

--OPTION 1

```
CREATE TABLE TRANS.ASSET_DAILY_INT(
    INT_READ_DT                        DATE             NOT NULL,
     ASSET_ID                        VARCHAR2(30)      NOT NULL,  
     MINUTES                         NUMBER (2,0)       NOT NULL,  
    INT_VALUE                   FLOAT(126)              NOT NULL,
    **INT_TYPE                    VARCHAR2(30)          NOT NULL,**
   ASSET_TYPE                     NUMBER(38,0),
    INT_SUM_DAY_USG                  FLOAT(126),
    HIGHEST_INT_DAY_USG              FLOAT(126),
    CREATED_DT                       DATE,
    MODIFIED_DT                      DATE,
     )

TABLESPACE TRANS
PARALLEL(DEGREE 4 INSTANCES 1)
PARTITION BY RANGE(MDM_READ_DT)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN ('01-JAN-2010'));
```

--OPTION 2 how do i model the column interval-type in Option--2? such that we can capture the interval type??

```
CREATE TABLE TRANS.ASSET_DAILY_INT(
    INT_READ_DT                        DATE             NOT NULL,
     ASSET_ID                        VARCHAR2(30)      NOT NULL,  
    INT_VALUE_0000                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0015                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0030                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0045                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0100                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0115                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0130                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0145                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0200                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0215                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0230                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0245                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0300                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0315                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0330                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0345                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0400                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0415                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0430                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0445                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0500                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0515                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0530                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0545                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0600                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0615                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0630                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0645                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0700                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0715                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0730                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0745                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0800                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0815                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0830                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0845                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0900                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0915                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0930                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_0945                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1000                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1015                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1030                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1045                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1100                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1115                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1130                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1145                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1200                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1215                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1230                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1245                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1300                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1315                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1330                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1345                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1400                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1415                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1430                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1445                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1500                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1515                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1530                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1545                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1600                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1615                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1630                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1645                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1700                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1715                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1730                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1745                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1800                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1815                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1830                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1845                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1900                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1915                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1930                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_1945                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2000                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2015                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2030                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2045                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2100                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2115                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2130                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2145                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2200                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2215                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2230                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2245                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2300                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2315                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2330                   FLOAT(126),
    INT_VALUE_2345                   FLOAT(126),
    ASSET_TYPE                     NUMBER(38,0),
    INT_SUM_DAY_USG                  FLOAT(126),
    HIGHEST_INT_DAY_USG              FLOAT(126),
    CREATED_DT                       DATE,
    MODIFIED_DT                      DATE,
     )
TABLESPACE TRANS
PARALLEL(DEGREE 4 INSTANCES 1)
PARTITION BY RANGE(MDM_READ_DT)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN ('01-JAN-2010'));
```

Comment: Option 2 is terrible. Don't do it that way; you will be unable to use the data. Every single query you will try to write against it will be a nightmare. Then: When you say "interval_type" (as "estimated" vs. "actual") what do you mean? Surely you don't mean that the interval itself is estimated vs. actual; what is? The data you get from the "asset"? (What is an "asset" anyway, I haven't heard of "assets" that send data. Are they some kind of spies? I think they do call spies "assets". Or are they some sort of sensors or meters?)

Comment: assets or meters . why do u say option 2 is terrible??? can u give some examples please.. Option 1 increases the volume by 10 times.. which effects the performance

Comment: Option 1 increases volume by 10 times because it duplicates a lot of data. That data doesn't belong in this table! Some of it belongs in other tables, and some of it is calculated, so it doesn't belong in ANY table. For example, you should not store info about "assets" (other than a unique ASSET_ID) in the table where you record the measurements. You should not store the "date" - only the start or the end time of the interval (in DATE data type, which in Oracle stores the date and the time-of-day together, rather than in the MINUTE column of data type NUMBER).

Comment: Examples for option 2 = *bad*: You want to see average usage, for example, between 1 PM and 3 PM. Or, better, between two user inputs: FROM_HOUR and TO_HOUR. For the first one you must average over eight columns (and handle nulls, since null across a row is not handles the same way as in a column, with aggregate functions); and the "dynamic" query is not even possible, because which columns must be read depends on the inputs, and columns must be hard-coded in a query. You will need dynamic SQL for a trivial task.

Comment: Have you considered not using a RDBMS at all? What are you constraints - does it need to read fast, write fast? Are there cost constraints on disk storage, hardware? Have a quick read of this just to open your horizons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833461/best-way-to-store-sensor-data-for-fast-reads

Comment: My constraint is that we have existing model that has 6 years of history perfectly working with option-2. Now they wanted to store interval_type and associate that to each interval reading. How can we modify the option 2 design to incorporate this new requirement without re creating a new model, thus impacting all our downstream and upstream design/ applications?